# "This interaction failed" error in command (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js, slash

I'm working on a randominteger slash command in discord.js

It supposed to work like this : 
Discord User : /randominteger minimal:1 maximal:10

Bot : (embed)
Random number 
4 
1 - 10

But instead the bot just says "This interaction failed"

I don't know why the bot says that though.
Can someone explain how it happened and how to fix it?

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, SlashCommandStringOption } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {  MessageEmbed  } = require('discord.js')
const color = "#ffed47"


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('randominteger')
        .setDescription('Replies with a random integer!')
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName('minimal')
                .setDescription('The minimal integer for the random integer')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName('maximal')
                .setDescription('The maximal integer for the random integer')
                .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const minimal = interaction.options.getInteger("minimal")
        const maximal = interaction.options.getInteger("maximal")
        minimal = Math.ceil(minimal)
        maximal = Math.floor(maximal)
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximal+0.1 - minimal) + minimal);

        const random = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(color)
        .setTitle("Random Number")
        .setDescription(String(randomNumber))
        .setFooter(String(minimal) + " - " + String(maximal))
        await interaction.reply({embeds : [random]})
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just didn't implement the the command properly xd

It worked.. with a 1 thing, you need to change the minimal and maximal variable to "var" not "const" (so the minimal and maximal variable can be used)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).